# mk# not found when I try to update-grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, grub

I originally posted this on stack overflow but it was taken down, and I was prompted to post it here.

Please tell me if you need any additional information.

I changed `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `-1` and when I saved it and tried to `update-grub` this was printed and I'm not sure how to solve it.

The error I'm receiving:

[image: error]

What the text file looks like:

[image: file]

Comment: Our sister site explains [why you shouldn't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). The reasoning applies here on Super User as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of the file starts with `mk#`. It's a comment that should start with `#`. You have probably inserted `mk` by mistake. Remove these two letters.